# EXCEL Formula: Multiply SUMIFS outcome with the corresponding row value from a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to use SUMIFS and multiply its output with the a values from the corresponding row. Example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqATs.png)

In This example I will use just 1 criteria for the SUMIFS, but the concept remains the same:
SUMIFS(C2:C5; B2:B5; "=Sum"). This would return 5 + 6 = 11
Now I want to multiple that by the corresponding probability. Meaning 5 * 50% + 6 * 20%: SUMIFS(C2:C5; B2:B5; "=Sum") *

Any idea how to include the probability in the equation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SUMIFS` for this unless you add a helper column - try using `SUMPRODUCT` instead

`=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5="Sum")+0;C2:C5;D2:D5)`

`SUMPRODUCT` multiplies all the arrays/ranges and then sums the result, so we can include your `value` and `probability` ranges with a conditional array based on `"Sum"` in the `include` range

With a helper column you can just use column `E` to multiply `C` and `D`, e.g. this formula in `E2` copied down

`=C2*D2`

and then use `SUMIFS` like this

`=SUMIFS(E2:E5;B2:B5;"Sum")`